# Find a composition series of $D_8$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups, dihedral-groups

**Answer**: Let $D_8=\langle a,b\rangle=\{e,a,a^2,a^3,b,ba,ba^2,ba^3\}$, where $a^4 = b^2 = e$ and $ab = ba^{-1}$ as usual.

Then

$$\{e\}\lhd\langle a^2\rangle\lhd\langle a\rangle\lhd D_8$$ or

$$\{e\}\lhd\{e,a^2\}\lhd\{e,a,a^2,a^3\}\lhd\{e,a,a^2,a^3,b,ba,ba^2,ba^3\}$$
is a subnormal series and all three factors have order two.

Since any group of order two is simple, this is a composition series

**Question**: Can someone explain how the three factors have order two.

Factors: quotient groups $G_1/G_0,G_2/G_1,...,G_n/G_{n-1}$.

Quotient group: $G/H$ for $H\leq G$ is the set of distinct left cosets that for an element of $x\in G$ and $x\not\in H$, the left coset is defined as $xH=\{xh\mid h\in H\}$

For $\{e,a^2\}/\{e\}$, we have $x=a^2$ and this is the set: $\{ea^2\}=\{a^2\}$ (order 1)

For $\{e,a,a^2,a^3\}/\{e,a^2\}$, we have $x=a,a^3$ giving $\{ae,aa^2,a^3e,a^3a^2\}=\{a,a^3\}$ (order 2)

For $\{e,a,a^2,a^3,b,ba,ba^2,ba^3\}/\{e,a,a^2,a^3\}$ I get $\{b,ba,ba^2,ba^3\}$ (order 4)

Where am I going wrong, I should have factors all of order $2$ but have factors of order $1,2$ and $4$

Comment: For finite groups $$|G/N|=\frac{|G|}{|N|}.$$

Comment: This is no substruction, but the cardinality of the quotient group.

Comment: Take the set ${{e}}$ and multiply all the elements inside it by the single elements in your group $e$ and then once again by $a^2$. Then you get two different cosets. That is using exactly the definition you provided.

Comment: @OfirSchnabel Thanks, I see that it must have order $2$, but cant break down the factors such that I can see that it has only $2$ elements. Also what is substruction?

Comment: @NotBuyingIt why do you multiply $e$ by $e$, I have defined the left cosets as being not in subgroup $H$, this is the definition from mathworld.wolfram, but perhapse I am misinterpreting it.

Comment: Dan, do you know what is a quotient group? you just need to find its cardinality.

Comment: So you cant compute the elements of a quotient group? Just its order?

Comment: Sure you can, up to representatives, look at my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left $\{e,a^2\}$ cosets of 
$\{e,a,a^2,a^3\}$ are
$$e\{e,a^2\},a\{e,a^2\}.$$
In particular there two of them.
You can think of $\bar{a},\bar{e}$ as the elements of the quotient group, but you can also take other representatives of the cosets.

Comment: Thanks I think I understand it now, are my answers as follows: $$\{e,a^2\}/\{e\}=e\{e\},a^2\{e\}$$ $$\{e,a,a^2,a^3\}/\{e,a^2\}=e\{e,a^2\},a\{e,a^2\}$$ $$\{e,a,a^2,a^3,b,ba,ba^2,ba^3\}/\{e,a,a^2,a^3\}=e\{e,a,a^2,a^3\},b\{e,a,a^2,a^3\}$$

Comment: Yes, and if you only need cardinality you can use the formula I gave above for finite groups. Notice that the reprasentatives are not unique, but the elements of the quotient group (these are sets) uniquely determined.

Comment: Perferct, I think I understand the fundamentals a lot better now.

Comment: I would like to suggest one more thing. When you stuck in this subject always ask yourself if you stuck in a "group problem" or a "quotient set" (with regards to equivalence relation) problem. Sometime it helps.